# Python's random.sample and stack overflow

Tags: python, random, multiprocessing

I've been working on a large Python scientific project, and I'm encountering a Stack overflow issue, which basically involves `random.sample()` and `multiprocessing`. I have a `Goo` object which contains a large population of `Foo`, who seek to make friends. To do so, they pick `p` other `Foo` belonging to `Goo` randomly using `random.sample()`. Once they are done, the program stops.

It goes this way:

foo.py

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.friends = []
```

goo.py:

```
from foo import Foo
import random

class Goo(object):
    def __init__(self, nfoo):
        self.foo_list = [Foo() for i in range(nfoo)]

    def sim_goo(self):
        for f in self.foo_list:
            candidates = random.sample(self.foo_list, 5)
            f.friends = candidates
```

and main.py:

```
from goo import Goo

def do_sim(argument):
    g = Goo(argument)
    g.sim_goo()
    return g
```

and using [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) I run:

```
from main import do_sim
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes = 2)
para_list = [1000, 1000]
result = pool.map_async(sim_goo, para_list).get()
```

which raises a `MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[<goo.Goo object at 0x0000003B15E60A90>]'. Reason: 'RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object',)'`

As it works with `para_list = [10, 10]`, I can only imagine that the error is raised because random.sample() gets too big to handle when the list it picks from is too large, which becomes problematic when using multiprocessing. But 1000 Foos isn't much.

Does anybody know an alternative?

Thanks for your time!

Best,

Comment: What is `do_sim`? This is the core of your code, and probably the reason of the issue.

Comment: You can also try increasing the maximum recursion depth

Comment: Oups! I forgot to add the main.py file, which is pretty small, but where do_sim is programmed. It's done now.

Comment: Yep, I tried to increase the maximum recursion depth, but it seems that I need to go to crazy high recursion depth for this to work, and it's a short-sighted approach as this code will grow. I'm an amateur programmer, and I thought that something more pythonic should be doable, hence my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your `Goo` object to be pickled (to transport it to another process), all of its `Foo`s must first be pickled.  To pickle each of those `Foo`s, all of their friend `Foo`s must first be pickled.  And to pickle *those* `Foo`s... and so on.  It's quite likely that there's going to be a chain of friendships that runs through all 1000 `Foo`s (and therefore requires a stack depth during the pickling process somewhat over 1000) - but the default recursion limit (on my copy of Python, at least) is only 1000.

If you can live with 1000 `Foo`s as your limit, you can probably bump up the recursion limit a bit - `sys.setrecursionlimit(1050)`, perhaps.  If you're going to ever need substantially more, a different approach is needed.  The first thing that comes to my mind is to store each `Foo`'s friendships as a list of indices into the `Goo`'s `foo_list`, rather than actual references to other `Foo`s.

Comment: Thanks! That's probably it. Nonetheless, when I do not use multiprocessing, it works without any issue. I can do one "do_sim(100000)" and it just takes time, but there is no stack overflow. That's what has been puzzling to me. I will definitely try to use the indexes!